# CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString() only processing up to 20 characters

Tags: macos, core-graphics

This function is called with very long strings:

```
void postBytes( UniChar *buf, UniCharCount len )
{
    CGEventSourceRef evtSrc = CGEventSourceCreate( kCGEventSourceStatePrivate );
    CGEventRef keyEvtDown = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent( evtSrc, 0, true );

    CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString( keyEventDown, len, buf );
    CGEventPost( kCGHIDEventTap, keyEventDown );

    CFRelease( keyEvtDown );
    CFRelease( evtSrc );
}
```

Regardless of the string provided as argument: When calling `CGEventPost()` only a maximum of 20 characters are posted to the event stream. This behaviour is not documented. What am I missing?